# What is gratis in reference to visa fees (Japan Visa)?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan

I am an Indian and I applied for a visa to Japan. We normally have to pay a visa fee of 440INR, but on my form, the person who took my documents circled "Gratis"  and told me that I don't have to pay anything.

I didn't ask then but I got really curious later. Why was I exempted from visa fees?

Edit: I applied for the Short term stay visa for 90 days, with an invitation from a Japanese national

Comment: What type of visa did you apply for?

Comment: The ["Visa fees" document](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/procedure/fee.html) at the Ministry of Foreign affairs indeed mentions *Depending on the purpose of your visit and your nationality, fees may not be required or may be a different amount.* but gives no further information. So what is the purpose of your visit?

Comment: I applied from the 90 days short term visa, with an invitation from a Japanese national

Comment: Do you hold an ordinary Indian passport (blue cover)?

Comment: gratis in general visa terminology means same as your country treats us in same type of visa, means fees, documents, restrictions etc.

Comment: @DavChana the word associated with the definition you describe is generally *reciprocal.  Gratis* simply means *free of charge.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two options:

1. You are planning to visit Japanese regions [affected by the recent earthquake](http://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/00_000260.html):

   > As part of the reconstruction assistance connected with the Great East
   >   Japan Earthquake, visa fee for foreign visitors to any region of
   >   Fukushima, Miyagi and Iwate Prefectures has been waived provided they
   >   satisfy the conditions below.
2. Since Japanese visa fees are [already low](http://www.ny.us.emb-japan.go.jp/pdfs/ryoji-tesuryo2017.pdf) ($7) for Indian citizens, the responsible person didn't want to bother with collecting it.
3. You hold an Indian diplomatic/service/official passport.

Comment: @JonothanReez 1. also requires a separate form to be filled out. http://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/files/000229488.pdf

Comment: @TheWandering consulate employees could easily ignore this rule and apply the gratis fee anyway

Comment: Whilst true, your insistence that fees are waived so readily does not match up with previous experiences / information I have been privy too. That isn't to say it doesn't happen, just that you seem to be a little too ready to mark it off as waived.

Comment: I think that's the reason. I'll be staying mostly in Sendai(part of the Miyagi prefecture) which is why I got the visa fees waived off.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder see OPs comment above :)

Comment: In which case the fees were exempted because of going to Tohoku. I was more referring to your second point (which as far as I know almost never happens). It is good that could all be clarified. Perhaps @Prathamaesh could put that last comment in the question?

Answer (score 0):

"Gratis" means "free". So, you do not need to pay a visa fee. This happens because India and Japan have an International Agreement to facilitate the visas between their nationals, signed in 2010.

Comment: Hi, for this to be a potentially good answer, can you provide some reference to the said agreement?